# GIMP 2.10 Lost Tool box

Tags: gimp

Somehow, through a series of mysterious keystrokes, the toolbox has disappeared from the side columns of Gimp. I have like on google and none of the answers seem to help. Is there a way to look at where local settings are saved.

I have like on google and none of the answers seem to help. I deleted and reinstalled Gimp, but the toolbox is still disappeared. Please help, obi wan.

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please delete this.

Answer (score 0):

**If you mean the tools palette** then the visibility is toggled with the Tab key.

**If you mean the Tool options** dialog:

- Click the `◁` icon on the right of the tab line where the Tool options usually appears

[image]

- Select `Add tab ➤ Tool options`
- You can drag the added tab index over the first tab index in the line to move the Tool options tab to the first position.
- You can avoid losing the Tool options dialog by locking it in place, after adding it, click the `◁` icon again and select `Lock tab to dock`.

For more details and screen shots see [here](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Getting-the-Tool-options-back-once-for-all)

**Otherwise if all else fails**, you can reset to factory settings like this (reinstall doesn't reset settings...): `Edit > Preferences > Interface > Window management > Window positions > Reset saved windows Positions to Defaults values`

[image]

See [here](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Managing-tool-options-and-window-positions) for some hints about managing your window positions.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with programming and is off topic. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Do not answer off topic questions. [answer] Vote to close them instead.